# How did Darth Maul's legs progress through the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-maul

After Darth Maul was brought back by Mother Talzin, his legs were a large pair of metal contraptions that work similar to that of, say, a raptor. Sometime after, he seemed to have developed a new pair of metallic legs, before finally regaining organic ones by the time he met his former master.

I have been unable to find any video of the Clone Wars that show the transitions, hence my question here. Throughout the Clone Wars starting from the moment he returned, what forms did his legs take, how did he get them, and how & why did he lose them before moving to the next form?

Comment: Based on my first reading of the title, I expected to hear that Darth Maul's lower half had been off on its own somewhere kicking Jedi in the shins.

Comment: one in front of the other I believe....left, right, left, right, etc...

Comment: He doesn't get organic legs, he merely put on pants.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### A Darth Maul Leg Synopsis

After Obi-Wan cut him in half, Maul managed to find his way to a trash compactor, where the Star Wars Databank indicates he was dropped off on the junk planet Loto Minor, where his brother Savage Opress discovered that Maul, mad and living on rodents,

> had built hideous spider-like legs in place of his severed ones.

[image: spider legs]

Savage Opress returned with Maul, Talzin then replaced his legs with the raptor-like legs you spoke of, made from the remains of Separtist droids, as shown in Star Wars Clone Wars episode "Revenge". He later loses one of these legs (and Opress loses his arm) during a battle with Kenobi and Adi Gallia in the Clone Wars episode "Revival".

[image: raptorlegs]

In their escape from Kenobi, Opress and Maul were then rescued (they had run out of oxygen) by the Death Watch, who took them to the planet Zanbar.

> On Zanbar, medical droids healed Maul from his wounds and replaced the
>   legs he had received from Mother Talzin for a pair of Human mechanical
>   legs that returned him to his previous height.

This is shown in the Clone Wars episode "Eminence".

[image: humanlegs]

At no point could I find a reference to him getting new organic legs, however it appears that in the time between Clone Wars and Rebels, he did get an upgrade of new, even sleeker legs - though this could merely be due to the art shift between series.

[image: more human legs]

Note that these legs have the same patellar plate as the legs Maul used when he tried to fight Sidious with Opress.
Moreover, these legs

> appear to be the same ones he wears in the Solo movie.

Comment: @RedCaio I replaced it with a higher def version of the same picture shortly before you posted on it. Sorry, rolled back!

Comment: Wait, so the legs he had when he fought Sidious was the same mechanical legs as the second form after he was brought back?

Comment: @thegreatjedi It appears that he has the same legs, or legs of a nearly identical design, between fighting Sidious at the end of Clone Wars and coming back in Rebels.

Comment: @Axelrod What I mean is, if the legs Mother Talzin gave him is the first incarnation of his new legs, then the ones he had when he first met Sidious was only the second, mechanical incarnation? I was under the impression they are his third, organic incarnation.

Comment: @thegreatjedi There don't appear to be any organic legs after he lost the originals.

Comment: The first image seems to be broken. (And it's not just part of the HTTP/HTTPS thing; it shows as being broken all the way from the first revision of this post.)

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork to put this together.

Answer (score 0):

Maul has no organic legs. Here is a list of his legs after Naboo.

1. Spider-Legs
2. Raptor Legs
3. Humanoid Legs (still Mechanical)

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is still wondering, Rebels S03E02 confirms his legs are still mechanical, and not organic, implying the difference in aesthetics is indeed due to art-style.

In this episode Maul is referred to as 'part droid' by Herra, and his legs are affected by magnetic fields.

Comment: Can you provide an image or a clip. Or a quote from the screenplay?